# Getting an indexed hash as a result from activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

Is there a way to pull records from activerecord in a hash already indexed by id instead of an array?
This is what im currently doing:

```
results = {}
Table.select { |current| results[current.id] = current }
```

Im assuming that there has to be a method that does that?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
Table.all.index_by { |t| t.id }
```

Or:

```
Table.all.index_by(&:id)
```

if you're into the whole brevity thing.

Comment: Thanks Jim! what if I want to do in-place modifications?

Comment: I don't know of a good way to do that.  You could do something like `Hash[Table.all.map {|t| t.something = "override"; [t.id, t]}]`.  There are potential gotchas there if you're trying to change records on the fly, but it may help you.

Comment: Link to documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_by